# Dynamic base url with angularjs

Tags: uri, javascript

I have create 2 angular app into drupal 7 like

```
"example.com"
"example.com/app1"
"example.com/app2"
```

example.com is my main site. So, when I set html5 pushstate enable for removing hash in angular apps, I got nobase error from angularjs. Coz,

```
<base href="">
```

require for enable angularjs html5 pushstate.

My question is, since i have multiple angualr app in this drupal site, how can i dynamically add conditional base url for "/app1" and "app2" ?

anybody can help me?
Waiting for response. Thanx.

Comment: nobody here to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add base element to your sites theme template file:

```
YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_html(&$variables, $hook) {
    $url = 'default';// default url
    if($application1) {// your condition for app1
      $url = 'app1';
    } elseif($application2) {// your condition for app2
    $url = 'app2';
    }
    $data = array(
      '#tag' => 'base',
      '#attributes' => array(
      'href' => $url,
      ),
    );
    drupal_add_html_head($data, 'base_href');
}
```

Put it into your template.php

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725528/3770000